# How to get .date style in uppercase?

Tags: swift, text, formatting

If I've got this text block

```
 Text("Logged On: \(theDate, style: .date))")
```

Is there anything I can do to get the date text converted to all caps? Just adding a

```
.textCase(.uppercase)
```

isn't working.

Comment: Sorry if I am understanding the question wrong but how do you want to convert a date to uppercased?

Comment: @Torke Something like "AUGUST 29, 2023"? What's hard to understand?

Comment: @Sweeper I somehow read over the example given. Forgot that date is not always written as only numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using the `style:` parameter, which takes a`Text.DateStyle`, use the `format:` parameter, which takes a `FormatStyle`. The latter is much more customisable.

You can make your own `FormatStyle`, and pass it to `format`:

```
struct CapitalisedFormatStyle: FormatStyle {
    func format(_ value: Date) -> String {
        // delegate to the built-in date format style
        Date.FormatStyle(date: .long).format(value)
            .localizedUppercase
            // or just .uppercased() if you prefer
    }
}

// for easy access with just .capitalisedDate
extension FormatStyle where Self == CapitalisedFormatStyle {
    static var capitalisedDate: CapitalisedFormatStyle { .init() }
}
```

```
Text("Logged On: \(someDate, format: .capitalisedDate)")
```